# Calculate average days between dates continuously updating

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, datediff

Hi I am looking for a formula solution that calculates the average days between dates that appear in a row. The tricky part is that new dates are added to each row every so often. This is for a plant watering schedule in google sheets which you can view here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_w5nqlQDtHTrepfhUWOeCXALR0vjBGW4cxq8-KxcaqU/edit?usp=sharing
Each row keeps a record of the dates I water each plant. When I check the box in column D, the current date (i.e. today) is automatically created in column E and previous dates shift over 1 column - continuously adding the new dates I water the plants.
I want a formula to calculate the average days between the dates that are in each row. But I also want the formula to account for the fact that new dates will be added, with the newest date to appear in column E and older dates extending back to columns F, G, H, etc to infinity...
I want the average days to appear in Column C.
The File I have shared is editable and you can trial how the sheet works there as it is a copy of my original sheet.
Suggestions and solutions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(iferror(AVERAGE(offset(E2,,,,sumproduct(--(E2:2<>""))-1)-offset(F2,,,,sumproduct(--(E2:2<>""))-1))))
```

and drag below

[image]

Comment: formula stops working after adding multiple date stamps

Comment: right ! I add arrayformula

Comment: pls, check E2:F2, there avg days between the dates 17/04/2022 and 17/04/2022 shows 6 days

Comment: because Q2 and R2 were not empty!

Comment: Most of the rows work, but for some reason some of the rows - specifically Row 4 is miscalculating average days. Current Avg day is 10. If I add todays date, which is about 4 days from the previous date, the average goes up, when in fact "4" should be drawing down the average. Not sure why this is occurring here, but seems to work elsewhere.

Comment: sorry, there was a lack of one comma `offset(E4,,,,sumproduct(--(E4:4<>""))-1)` , I have corrected the answer

Comment: that's working like a charm @MikeSteelson. Thanks once again!